# Javascript How to canvas drawing work on Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile, html5-canvas

I want to make canvas drawing but this code not working on Mobile browser

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("draw");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 60;
    canvas.height = 400;
    
    let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    let draw_color = "black";
    let draw_width = "2";
    let is_drawing = false;

    canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", start, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", draw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", start, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw, false);

    canvas.addEventListener("touchend", stop, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", stop, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", stop, false);


    function start(event) {
        is_drawing = true;
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
                       event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    
    function draw(event) {
        if (is_drawing) {
            context.lineTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
                           event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
            context.strokeStyle = draw_color;
            context.lineWidth = draw_width;
            context.lineCap = "round";
            context.lineJoin = "round";
            context.stroke();
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    function stop(event) {
        if (is_drawing) {
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();
            is_drawing = false;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function draw(event) {
   e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (is_drawing) {
        context.lineTo(event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft,
                       event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
        context.strokeStyle = draw_color;
        context.lineWidth = draw_width;
        context.lineCap = "round";
        context.lineJoin = "round";
        context.stroke();
    }
}
```